# RESTful URL design for Widgets Check

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, widget, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building a RESTful API for a web site that allows users to create widgets and tabs containing widgets (think igoogle.com/ netvibes.com) and I want to share my URL design for your insights.

Here are the simple rules:

1. There is a static list of widgetTypes available for a user to pick.
2. A user can create one or more widgetInstances of each widgetType.
3. A user can create one or more tabs/ dashboards containing widgetInstances

This API needs to only serve JSON that will be consumed by JavaScript. We can also assume that all authentication will be taken care of through cookies.

The API needs to serve:

1. CRUD of user's Tabs
2. CRUD of specific user widgetInstances
3. Retrieval of all tabs for a user
4. Retrieval of all widgetInstances for a given tab.
5. Retrieval of all available widgetTypes for a user to add widgets from.

**Design:**

**Tab controller:**

widgetAPI.com/tabs -> Returns meta data (id, title) of all tabs available to a user.

widgetAPI.com/tabs/1 -> Returns meta data (title) of tab id 1. If sent with POST, updates tab id 1.

widgetAPI.com/tabs/1/widgets > Returns all widgetInstances of tab id 1.

**Question 1:** Ideally I'd like to follow the design of widgetAPI.com/tabs/1 also returning all the widgetInstances of the given tab but with that design, widgetAPI.com/tabs may return far too much data as I would have to return all the widgets for all the tabs. Hence I need to create a separate "widgetAPI.com/tabs/1/widgets" URL but that also has to return the tab meta data as I don't want to make two HTTP calls to get meta data & widgets. Please advise as I am not sure of the best approach here.

widgetAPI.com/tabs/create -> Create a new tab

widgetAPI.com/tabs/delete/123 -> Delete tabid 123

**Widget Controller:**

widgetAPI.com/widgets/123 -> Return data for widgetInstanceId 123. Updates 123 if sent through POST.

widgetAPI.com/widgets/Create?typeID = 2 -> Creates a new widgetInstance of typeid = 2. This will only be a POST request so typeId could be a post parameter.

widgetAPI.com/widgets/delete/123 -> Delete widgetInstance 123

**Question 2** So there is one rule I havent been able to fulfill yet. I need to return all the widgetTypes available and I am not sure how to fit this request into the previous two controllers. I am currently leaning towards just serving this separately. So something like widgetAPI.com/getWidgetTypes. Thoughts?

Thanks guys. If you could critique on the overall design, just address the questions or mention anything I should watch out for, that would be great as this is my first time designing a RESTful app. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using regular MVC controllers for this? Or WebAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> widgetAPI.com/tabs/1 -> Returns meta data (title) of tab id 1. If sent
>   with POST, updates tab id 1.

A POST to the above URL should not update tab 1. A PUT to that URL should update tab 1.

> widgetAPI.com/tabs/create -> Create a new tab

To create a new tab, you should POST to widgetAPI.com/tabs

> widgetAPI.com/tabs/delete/123 -> Delete tabid 123

To delete tab 123, send a DELETE to widgetAPI.com/tabs/123

> widgetAPI.com/widgets/123 -> Return data for widgetInstanceId 123. Updates 123 if sent through POST

To update widget 123, send a PUT to widgetAPI.com/widgets/123

> widgetAPI.com/widgets/Create?typeID = 2 -> Creates a new widgetInstance of typeid = 2. This will only be a POST request so typeId could be a post parameter.

To create a new widget, send a POST to widgetAPI.com/widgets. The typeId should be part of the POST request body.

> widgetAPI.com/widgets/delete/123 -> Delete widgetInstance 123

To delete widget 123, send a DELETE request to widgetAPI.com/widgets/123

**Answer 1:** I like the `widgetAPI.com/tabs/1/widgets` URL design. Also, I like the idea of making 2 separate calls for the metadata and the data.

**Answer 2:** I think you should do this with a separate controller. I don't like the URL though. Instead, I like HTTP GET `widgetAPI.com/widget-types` or just `widgetAPI.com/widgettypes`.

As a general rule, unless you want your clients to be able to create URL identifiers, follow this pattern:

URL: /whatever-resource
GET - returns all resources of this type
POST - create a new resource

URL: /whatever-resource/{id}
GET - return single resource with that id
PUT - update resource with that id
DELETE - delete resource with that id

You can also allow PUT requests to /whatever-resource/{id} to create a resource, but the client / user must specify the id (implicitly, the URL, since the URL contains the id). If you don't want users to provide this, but rather have the server generate it, then POST to /whatever-resource to create the resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I understand, some browsers have limitations on PUT and DELETE right? Can I still rely on those two HTTP verbs and take them out of the URL like you mentioned?

Comment: That's why I put up the comment. You could fake a PUT or DELETE with an X-HTTP-Override if using plain MVC. There is an HtmlHelper for that. You might also want to look into AttributeRouting.NET, especially its `RestfulRouteConventionAttribute`.

Comment: Using regular MVC controller but I have the freedom to switch to WebAPI. Would that help?

Comment: Not for serving up web pages. WebAPI can serve up data in JSON or XML format. You can still have PUT and DELETE actions in regular MVC, but you have to use the http method overrides. Again, I would refer you to check out the pattern used in AttributeRouting.NET's RestfulRouteConversion attribute.